# Javascript: using querySelectorAll to find all input elements matching certain conditions

Tags: javascript, selectors-api

I am creating a form.html page
and I am trying to get an array using Javascript in my form.js file with the 5 fields that the user should enter using **querySelectorAll**, but my code is not working.

What am I doing wrong? What I want my JS code to do is to find all fields that:

1. are input elements
2. start with "txt"
3. are either type="txt" or type="password"

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let divMain = document.getElementById("divMain");
  let inputElements = divMain.getElementById("frmRegister").querySelectorAll(input[id ^= txt][type = "text"], input[id ^= txt][type = "password"]);
  console.log(inputElements.length);
});
```

```html
<h2 class="container">Form/jQuery</h2>
<div class="container" id="divMain">
  <form action="form.html" method="get" name="frmRegister" id="frmRegister">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Login</td>
        <td><input required type="text" name="field1" id="txtfield1" />&nbsp;<span id="spnLogin"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" id="txtPassword">&nbsp;<span id="spnPasswordComplexity"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Confirm Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" id="txtConfirmPassword">&nbsp;<span id="spnPasswordCompare"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtEmail">&nbsp;<span id="spnEmail"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Confirm Email</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtConfirmEmail">&nbsp;<span id="spnEmailCompare"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" id="btnRegister" value="Register"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Try quotation marks like `querySelectorAll('input[id^="txt"][type="text"], input[id^="txt"][type="password"]')`

Comment: Made you a snippet. It gives clear console errors - no need to use a parent to get another element by id  - just use `document.getElementById("frmRegister")`

Comment: AND add quotes `let inputElements = document.getElementById("frmRegister").querySelectorAll('input[id^=txt][type="text"], input[id^=txt][type="password"]');
`

Answer (score 0):

You overcomplicate your selectors, are missing some quotes

```
 let inputElements = document.getElementById("frmRegister")
    .querySelectorAll('input[id^=txt][type="text"], input[id^=txt][type="password"]');
```

But it's easier using a filter:

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let inputElements = [...document.getElementById("frmRegister").querySelectorAll('input[id ^= txt]')]
    .filter(elem => elem.type === "text" || elem.type==="password");

  console.log(inputElements);
  // or
  inputElements.forEach(elem => console.log(elem.id,elem.type)); 
});
```

```html
<h2 class="container">Form/jQuery</h2>
<div class="container" id="divMain">
  <form action="form.html" method="get" name="frmRegister" id="frmRegister">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Login</td>
        <td><input required type="text" name="field1" id="txtfield1" />&nbsp;<span id="spnLogin"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" id="txtPassword">&nbsp;<span id="spnPasswordComplexity"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Confirm Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" id="txtConfirmPassword">&nbsp;<span id="spnPasswordCompare"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtEmail">&nbsp;<span id="spnEmail"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Confirm Email</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtConfirmEmail">&nbsp;<span id="spnEmailCompare"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" id="btnRegister" value="Register"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let inputElements = document.getElementById("frmRegister").querySelectorAll('input[id^=txt][type="text"], input[id^=txt][type="password"]');
  console.log(inputElements)
});
```

```html
<h2 class="container">Form/jQuery</h2>
<div class="container" id="divMain">
  <form action="form.html" method="get" name="frmRegister" id="frmRegister">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Login</td>
        <td><input required type="text" name="field1" id="txtfield1" />&nbsp;<span id="spnLogin"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" id="txtPassword">&nbsp;<span id="spnPasswordComplexity"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Confirm Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" id="txtConfirmPassword">&nbsp;<span id="spnPasswordCompare"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtEmail">&nbsp;<span id="spnEmail"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Confirm Email</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtConfirmEmail">&nbsp;<span id="spnEmailCompare"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" id="btnRegister" value="Register"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

All inputs

```js
window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  let inputElements = document.getElementById("frmRegister").querySelectorAll('input[id^=txt][type="text"], input[id^=txt][type="password"]');
  console.log(inputElements.length)
});
```

```html
<h2 class="container">Form/jQuery</h2>
<div class="container" id="divMain">
  <form action="form.html" method="get" name="frmRegister" id="frmRegister">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Login</td>
        <td><input required type="text" name="field1" id="txtfield1" />&nbsp;<span id="spnLogin"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" id="txtPassword">&nbsp;<span id="spnPasswordComplexity"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Confirm Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" id="txtConfirmPassword">&nbsp;<span id="spnPasswordCompare"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtEmail">&nbsp;<span id="spnEmail"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Confirm Email</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtConfirmEmail">&nbsp;<span id="spnEmailCompare"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" id="btnRegister" value="Register"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

[getElementById](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById) is part of document object but not of element object.

Your code with slight alteration.

```js
(function() {
  let divMain = document.getElementById("divMain");
  let inputElements = divMain.querySelector("#frmRegister").querySelectorAll('input[id^="txt"][type="text"], input[id^="txt"][type="password"]');
  console.log(inputElements);
})();
```

```html
<div class="container" id="divMain">
  <form action="form.html" method="get" name="frmRegister" id="frmRegister">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td>Login</td>
        <td><input required type="text" name="field1" id="txtfield1" />&nbsp;<span id="spnLogin"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" id="txtPassword">&nbsp;<span id="spnPasswordComplexity"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Confirm Password</td>
        <td><input type="password" id="txtConfirmPassword">&nbsp;<span id="spnPasswordCompare"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Email</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtEmail">&nbsp;<span id="spnEmail"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>Confirm Email</td>
        <td><input type="text" id="txtConfirmEmail">&nbsp;<span id="spnEmailCompare"></span></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" id="btnRegister" value="Register"></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </form>
</div>
```